# Generate report from Nunit test result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I know this question is raised by many times in this forum. But I could not find any straightforward answer to this question. So the question is

Is there any Nuget package which can convert Nunit test result(see below image) in to a report?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can research **Importing NUnit XML reports** to have xml file, then can implement the result to any file you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Allure

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2 - global repo

https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit - for NUnit

[image: Allure]